# Copy output data from a `for loop` to a text document in Python

Tags: file, python-3.x, copy, document

The code I'm working on opens a text file, prints the text file to python terminal then goes through the entire document copying all the words with the character 'e' and prints those to the terminal as well. It's then supposed to write those words to a separate text document.

```
file = open("myfile.txt", 'r')
output = open("outputfile.txt", 'w')
file = file.read()
print(file)
enter = input('Press enter to see all words with e.')
for words in file.split(' '):
    if 'e' in words:
        print(words)
        output.write(words)

output.close()
```

The program runs fine until it has to copy the text from the loop to `outputfile.txt`.

The result should like this in the output file:

```
The
extra
three.
document.
...
```

But instead the output file looks like:

```
Thisextrathree.The
...
```

It keeps some words that didn't appear in the loop and presses everything together. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Just add a `"\n"` - `output.write(words + "\n")`

Comment: To jump lines you need to add \n because you're just adding words to the file ex: you add The, now the file has this text: The, then you add extra so its basically like this : The+extra so the file will have Theextra if you dont want this to happen you have to do something like: output.write(words+"\n")

Comment: Awesome that fixes the new line problem, but I sill have the problem of some words being in the `outputfile.txt` that don't belong there like 'both', 'this', and 'to'.